# sorting 6 numbers with minimum comparisons

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I want to write an algorithm (c++)
that reads 6 numbers in this way:

x1 > x2 > x3

and

y1 > y2 > y3

these two statements are known to us
but now we want to sort all of 6 numbers just using basic syntax and minimum comparison

what should I do?

thanks a lot !!

Comment: "_what should I do?_" Try to solve the problem on your own, and come back to SO, once you have a specific issue with your solution.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask].

Comment: Since both parts are internally ordered it's more a question of merging than sorting.

Comment: `std::array<int.6> sort6(int x1, int x2, int x3, int y1, int y2, int y3) { std:::array<int,6> result = {x1,x2,x3,y1,y2,y3}; std::sort(result.begin(), result.end()); return result;}`

Comment: I have tried 3 or 4 ways, but it takes at least 6 or 7 comparisons ! And its not a cpp program, its just a flowchart algorithm ! And it should be sorted in 3-5 comparisons. BTW I am new in this field, and I don’t exactly know the system of asking and answering here !

Comment: What makes you think you can solve this problem with 5 or fewer comparisons?

Comment: It is some kind of homework assignment !

Comment: The best way to approach this type of problem is to get out a pencil and some paper and draw pictures. Or get some playing cards and arrange six of them in the prescribed starting position. Then start trying to figure out how you would solve the problem. What is unique about the relationships? For example, you know that if `y1 > x1`, then it's also greater than `x2` and `x3`. What can you do with that information. You're not going to solve this problem by writing code. You're going to solve this problem by experimenting with a physical model. *Then* write code to implement the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 20 combinations, so with ideal splits it can be done with 5 comparisons. (2**5 allows 32 groups).

```
// x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
// x1 x2 y1 x3 y2 y3
// x1 x2 y1 y2 x3 y3
// x1 x2 y1 y2 y3 x3
// x1 y1 x2 x3 y2 y3
// x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
// x1 y1 x2 y2 y3 x3
// x1 y1 y2 y3 x2 x3
// x1 y1 y2 x2 y3 x3
// x1 y1 y2 x2 x3 y3
// y1 x1 y2 y3 x2 x3
// y1 x1 y2 x2 y3 x3
// y1 x1 y2 x2 x3 y3
// y1 x1 x2 x3 y2 y3
// y1 x1 x2 y2 x3 y3
// y1 x1 x2 y2 y3 x3
// y1 y2 y3 x1 x2 x3
// y1 y2 x1 y3 x2 x3
// y1 y2 x1 x2 y3 x3
// y1 y2 x1 x2 x3 y3
```

- So first split with `x1 < y1` to form two groups of 10

  ```
  // x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
  // x1 x2 y1 x3 y2 y3
  // x1 x2 y1 y2 x3 y3
  // x1 x2 y1 y2 y3 x3
  // x1 y1 x2 x3 y2 y3
  // x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
  // x1 y1 x2 y2 y3 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 y3 x2 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 x2 y3 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 x2 x3 y3
  ```

  and

  ```
  // y1 x1 y2 y3 x2 x3
  // y1 x1 y2 x2 y3 x3
  // y1 x1 y2 x2 x3 y3
  // y1 x1 x2 x3 y2 y3
  // y1 x1 x2 y2 x3 y3
  // y1 x1 x2 y2 y3 x3
  // y1 y2 y3 x1 x2 x3
  // y1 y2 x1 y3 x2 x3
  // y1 y2 x1 x2 y3 x3
  // y1 y2 x1 x2 x3 y3
  ```

The 2 groups would use identical logic, so using the group beginning with `x1`:

- We can split for `y1 < x2` (2nd split)

  ```
  // x1 x2 x3 y1 y2 y3
  // x1 x2 y1 x3 y2 y3
  // x1 x2 y1 y2 x3 y3
  // x1 x2 y1 y2 y3 x3

  // x1 y1 x2 x3 y2 y3
  // x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
  // x1 y1 x2 y2 y3 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 y3 x2 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 x2 y3 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 x2 x3 y3
  ```

For the first group of 4, we have to place `x3` in correct place between all the  `y`s:

- split with `x3 < y2` then depending of the side compare with `y1` or `y3` (2 additional splits -> 4 comparisons)

For the second group (6 possibilities):

- split first by `x2 < y2` (3rd split)

  ```
  // x1 y1 x2 x3 y2 y3
  // x1 y1 x2 y2 x3 y3
  // x1 y1 x2 y2 y3 x3
  // placing x3 correctly with y2, y3 (2 split required -> total 5 comparisons)

  // x1 y1 y2 y3 x2 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 x2 y3 x3
  // x1 y1 y2 x2 x3 y3
  // placing y3 correctly with x2, x3
  ```

As exercise, you can try different splits (as for example firstly split with `x2 < y2`), your split should divide the remaining group in 2 sub groups of similar size. (a group of at most `2**N` should forms two groups of at most `2**(N-1)` as the group of 10 (`<= 16`) which has formed one group of 4 and one group of 6 (`<= 8`)).